# Riemannian submersions with negatively curved fibers

Tags: riemannian-geometry, foliations

Are there some known examples of totally geodesic Riemannian submersions:
$$
\pi : N \to M
$$
such that:

1) $N$ is a compact Riemannian manifold

2) $M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold with positive Ricci curvature.

3) The fibers of $\pi$ have negative Ricci curvature in $\mathbb{N}$.

4) The distribution orthogonal to the fibers is everywhere bracket generating ?

According to Theorem D in "[Totally geodesic foliations on 4-manifolds](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/totallygeodesic.pdf)" by G. Cairns and E. Ghys, this seems impossible when $\dim M=2$ and $\dim N=4$ because 1) and 3) would imply that the distribution orthogonal to the fibers is actually integrable. But are there similar results in higher dimensions ?